# Swift Core Data Batch Updating creating duplicate records instead of overwriting

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, nspredicate, batch-updates

It seems like my `NSPredicate` isn't working when updating `Core Data` records. When doing a fetch request, the same `NSPredicate` works with no issues.

When I do a `Batch Update`, it just creates new duplicate records instead of overwriting the existing ones as intended. Why oh why?

Here is my code that does the updating:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

lazy var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    if let managedObjectContext = self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext {
        return managedObjectContext
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
    }()

func doesMessageExist(id: String) -> Bool {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ChatMessage")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1

    let count = managedObjectContext!.countForFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil)
    return (count > 0) ? true : false
}

func updateMessage(chatMessage: ChatMessage) {
    var batchRequest = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entityName: "ChatMessage")

    if doesMessageExist(chatMessage.id) {
        batchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", chatMessage.id)
    }

    batchRequest.propertiesToUpdate = [
        "id" : chatMessage.id,
        "senderUserId" : chatMessage.senderUserId,
        "senderUsername" : chatMessage.senderUsername,
        "receiverUserId" : chatMessage.receiverUserId,
        "receiverUsername" : chatMessage.receiverUsername,
        "messageType" : chatMessage.messageType,
        "message" : chatMessage.message,
        "timestamp" : chatMessage.timestamp
    ]

    batchRequest.resultType = .UpdatedObjectsCountResultType
    var error : NSError?
    var results = self.managedObjectContext!.executeRequest(batchRequest, error: &error) as NSBatchUpdateResult
    if error == nil {
        println("Update Message: \(chatMessage.id) \(results.result)")
        appDelegate.saveContext()
    }
    else {
        println("Update Message Error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Here is my **ChatMessage** class:

```
class ChatMessage: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var id: String
    @NSManaged var message: String
    @NSManaged var messageType: String
    @NSManaged var receiverUserId: String
    @NSManaged var receiverUsername: String
    @NSManaged var senderUserId: String
    @NSManaged var senderUsername: String
    @NSManaged var timestamp: NSDate

}
```

Here is the Core Data stack in my AppDelegate:

```
lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.walintukai.LFDate" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1] as NSURL
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("LFDate", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("LFDate.sqlite")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
        coordinator = nil
        // Report any error we got.
        let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if coordinator == nil {
        return nil
    }
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSOverwriteMergePolicy
    return managedObjectContext
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
            var error: NSError? = nil
            if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                NSLog("Database Save Error: \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Sadly, there is no documentation for `NSBatchUpdateRequest` (shame on you, Apple!). But batch update requests were covered at WWDC 2014, session 225 (here's the [ASCII transcript](http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/225)).

In the session, it is mentioned that batch updates bypass `NSManagedObjectContext` and make changes directly in the persistent store. So you have to refresh the objects by yourself:

> So if you're interested in updating your database en masse, setting a flag on a particular column for example, and then reflecting those changes in the UI, you're going to need to get the results or the Managed Object IDs back, so you can tell the object, tell the Managed Object Context to refresh the objects with those IDs.

You have to specify other `resultType` for batch request:

```
batchRequest.resultType = .UpdatedObjectIDsResultType
```

And then after executing request you have to refresh objects using the returned array of `NSManagedObjectID` (code sample from [Big Nerd Ranch](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/new-in-core-data-and-ios-8-batch-updating/), rewritten in Swift):

```
for objectsID in objectsIDs {
    var error : NSError? = nil
    if let object = context.existingObjectWithID(objectsID as NSManagedObjectID, error: &error) {
        context.refreshObject(object, mergeChanges: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is such a huge improvement and it doesn't come with docs? Come on, Apple

Comment: I don't understand why you want this to perform I/O. instead you should probably use `objectRegisteredForID`?

Comment: It's 2021 and still apple has not documented this. Unreal!

Answer (score 2):

Try this code for NSBatchUpdateRequest with out duplicating the records in swift3

```
func batchUpdate{ 
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
        let batchRequest = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entityName: "ENTITY_NAME")
        batchRequest.propertiesToUpdate = [ "PROPERTY_NAME" : "CHANGE_VALUE`enter code here`"]
        batchRequest.resultType = .updatedObjectIDsResultType

        do{
           let objectIDs = try managedContext.execute(batchRequest) as! NSBatchUpdateResult
           let objects = objectIDs.result as! [NSManagedObjectID]

            objects.forEach({ objID in
                let managedObject = managedContext.object(with: objID)
                managedContext.refresh(managedObject, mergeChanges: false)
            })
        } catch {
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `doesMessageExist` function is wrong.

You check for the count for the fetch request not equalling `NSNotFound`, which it will only do in the case of an error. If the message can't be found, it will return zero, if it can be found, it will return one (or more, if you have multiple objects with the same ID).

At the moment your code will be saying that the message always exists.

None of the code in this question is creating new objects, by the way, and `executeRequest` isn't a method on NSManagedObjectContext, so you should probably include your implementation of that in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed my `doesMessageExist` return function to: `return (count > 0) ? true : false;`. Also, the `executeRequest` function is a default function for `NSManagedObjectContext` for me. I didn't implement an `extension`. I just followed the directions in this [link](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/core-data-in-swift-tutorial-part-1/). I know it is making duplicate records because of this println message: `println("Update Message: \(chatMessage.id) \(results.result)")`. The results.result number keeps going up whenever it does an update.

Comment: `executeRequest()` and `NSBatchUpdateRequest` was introduced in iOS 8.0. It is listed in [iOS 8.0 API Diffs/CoreData Changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS80APIDiffs/frameworks/CoreData.html), but the [NSManagedObjectContext Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html) does not cover it yet.

Comment: @MartinR `executeRequest` may not be covered in the class reference yet, but it definitely is working and does make changes to my `Core Data`. Although, if it is working correctly is another matter as it is not paying attention to my `NSPredicate`.

Comment: @TheNomad: My comment was only meant as a response to jrturton's statement *"executeRequest isn't a method on NSManagedObjectContext"*.

Comment: @martinr I thought it was a method on the persistent store coordinator, not the context? I wish they'd keep the docs up to date.

Comment: @jrturton: According to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS80APIDiffs/frameworks/CoreData.html it is a method on the context. But I haven't used it yet, so I cannot say more about it.

Comment: It is a metod on `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator/executeRequest:withContext:error:. It makes sense as batch updates operate directly on the persistent store, bypassing the context.